# Array cleaning in C

Tags: c, arrays

I don't know how to clean an array from the elements which indexes stored in the other array. I need to complete the following C-program consisting of main(…) and function

```
void clear_MSBs( unsigned char dest_array[], unsigned char array_indices []).
```

Beginning of code:

```
#define N 8
#define M 5
int main()
{
    unsigned char dest_array[N] = {248,249,250,251,252,253,254,255};
    unsigned char array_indices[M] = {0,2,3,6,7}; // contains M=5 elements
    clear_MSBs(dest_array, array_indices);
    // print the modified dest_array[] here
    return 0;
}
```

Note: It is guaranteed that all indices stored in the second array are within the
allowed range.
I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: What is expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by cleaning, you mean marking the element as invalid (which is probably what you want), then you could just loop over the indices array, and use the i-th element of the indices array as the index for the destination array.

Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define N 8
#define M 5

void clear_MSBs(unsigned char dest_array[], unsigned char array_indices [])
{
    for(int i = 0; i < M; ++i)
        dest_array[array_indices[i]] = 0;
}

int main()
{
    unsigned char dest_array[N] = {248,249,250,251,252,253,254,255};
    unsigned char array_indices[M] = {0,2,3,6,7}; // contains M=5 elements
    clear_MSBs(dest_array, array_indices);
    // print the modified dest_array[] here
    for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        if(dest_array[i] != 0)
            printf("%d ", dest_array[i]);
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

> 249 252 253

PS: The code assumes that an invalid element has the 0 value.

Comment: yes, that is what I was asking! Thank you a lot, gsamaras!

Answer (score 0):

You just need to overwrite what you're deleting with the next value in the array, propagate that change, and then keep in mind where the new end is.

In C++, though, it would be better to use a std::vector:

```
std::vector<int> array; // initialize array... // delete element at index 2
array.erase(array.begin() + 2);
```